# "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

When implementing a similar solution I get the following error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

My variable id is as numeric and variable name is as varchar, and I want to show the name instead of the id

Tables:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
    [codigo],
    [descripcion] varchar,
    [fecha_ingreso] datatime,
    [valor] numeric,
    [stockMinimo] numeric ,
    [codigo_bodega] numeric (10,0)
FROM 
    [Bodega].[dbo].[Articulo]

SELECT TOP (1000) 
    [codigo] numeric (10,0),
    [descripcion] varchar (30)
FROM 
    [Bodega].[dbo].[Bodega]
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    articulo.codigo,
    articulo.fecha_ingreso,
    articulo.valor,
    articulo.stockMinimo,
    articulo.codigo_bodega
FROM
    Articulo
LEFT JOIN 
    Bodega ON Articulo.codigo_bodega = Bodega.descripcion
```

I want to show the `descripcion` but not the `codigo`

Comment: Clearly `descripcion` has values that aren't a valid numerical value. Considering that you are joining on the columns they should be the same data type, so the question is why are you using a `varchar` to store numerical data?

Comment: When creating the table, they are asking me for the codigo to be a numeric value and the descripcion to be a varchar type. And when showing the article it must show me it is the descripcion but not the codigo.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: It's just a stored procedure that shows me the fields of the Article table, which has a fk between codigo_bodega (tale Articulo) and codigo (table Bodega), but instead of it showing me the store codigo I want it to show me the name (descripcion) ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are joining on wrong column. Key column is codigo:

```
select articulo.codigo,
          articulo.fecha_ingreso,
          articulo.valor,
          articulo.stockMinimo,
          articulo.codigo_bodega, Bodega.descripcion
          from Articulo
       LEFT JOIN Bodega
          ON 
           Articulo.codigo_bodega=Bodega.codigo
```

Comment: They are asking me to show the descripcion, not the codigo

Comment: @Gabriela and you do. Check the added Bodega.descripcion column in the select. If you want to, you can remove the articulo.codigo_bodega fronm the select list.